# Is there a browser extension that bypasses restrictions of pasting passwords?

Tags: javascript, paste

As one example out of many, if you go to https://appleid.apple.com and click to manage your account, you can't paste your password in the password field. There is some javascript that prevents that.
Is there a convenient way to disable that? It breaks normal browser behavior to not be able to paste, and additionally, it discourages the use of strong passwords (I use a password manager and copy & paste from it to the site).

Thanks!

Comment: I am able to paste my password without any problems.  The simple way to prevent something like this is to disable said javascript.  I had no problem copying and pasting a password from LastPass.

Comment: Websites forcing javascript makes me a sad panda :( "To manage your Apple ID, your browser must support Javascript.

If you're using Safari, confirm that Javascript is enable in the Security pane of Safari Preferences.
" with noscript installed. Enabled scripts, can't paste password.

Comment: Note that Ctrl-V pastes into some fields even when the paste menu option is disabled.

Answer (score 5):

I created a JavaScript bookmarklet that removes all onpaste events from password fields. I haven't extensively tested it just yet, but I know it works on appleid.apple.com as that's the reason I wrote it.

See http://prioritized.net/blog/re-enabling-password-pasting-on-annoying-web-forms/

Comment: As a bookmarklet, it requires choosing that bookmarklet when on an offending site, right? Is it possible for this to be a browser extension that works everywhere? I saw your note on your post that you set this up for Mobile Safari as well. My guess is that a browser extension would work for Chrome on iOS as well. -Just some thoughts / the reason this doesn't solve it for me totally.

Comment: Yes, it could. I've never written an extension and use multiple browsers so I didn't really have an interest in doing so.

Comment: You're link is dead, please share the code here.

Answer (score 5):

bypass a website’s copy-paste restriction on Firefox:

type about:config in the URL. Find

> dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled

and set it to "false". (Firefox won't allow anymore the websites to mess with your clipboard).

All the glory to [digitwonk](http://digiwonk.wonderhowto.com/how-to/re-enable-copy-paste-annoying-sites-block-0155910/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Firefox add-on that certainly works for your example:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/righttoclick/

Not a perfect solution because you have to click the "right to click" icon first and then click and paste in the password box. But not bad.

Comment: This was a malicious addon and it was removed.

Answer (score 0):

The most bullet-proof way I can think of is to just temporarily disable JavaScript, then paste the password(s), then re-enable.

I had to do this with ebay just now, because even removing the onpaste attributes didn't help (and I didn't feel like spending any more time trying to uncover/bypass whatever other blocks they had in place).